# Google maps API disabled?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps, google-api

I have this simple code:

```
<html>
 <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBSB4gQMtgeyqNvwmORpW1rY_3wFYjGS9E&sensor=false">
    </script>
</html>
```

And when I run it locally, after a few seconds, it pops back an alert that says:

> "Google has disabled the use of Maps API for this application. See the
>   Terms of Service for more information..."

This is a new key I made by creating a "new browser key", and "any referrer is allowed". I've never used Google Maps API before, and I'm not doing anything against Google's TOS for them to disable my license.

Is there something wrong with my account, so that it'll automatically disable any key that I pass it? How could I check if I have any "holds" on my account?

Can I use the google api WITHOUT a license, if the license is my problem?

I'm still looking for answers on why I cannot use the simple snippet of code above to load the google maps API. It really shouldn't be this difficult. What kind of gotchas or traps am I falling into? What sort of research can I do to help me solve this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licenses

Comment: after a while...you should make your application [**public available**](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_9_1)

Comment: @Dr.Molle I'm just spinning this up to test it. This is the very first time I've attempted to use the Maps API, so this would be considered  the "development and testing phase", so I'm not charging or restricting anyone access to anything. So unless there's something flagged on my google account, there should be no reason why Google would be deactivating the key I made minutes before posting this question. Also, how do you know there's a problem with the license, or that this question is about licenses?

Comment: @Houseman what version are you using?

Comment: @malcolmmcswain what version of the API am I using? Whatever version I get from `maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js`

Comment: Ok, so you're using version 3, is that correct?

Comment: @malcolmmcswain I think so.

Comment: I guess you have to add your URL to authorized URLs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your URL(copied from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/auth):

> In order to prevent a third party from reusing your client ID on their
>   own website, the use of your client ID is restricted to a list of URLs
>   that you specifically authorize.
>
> To obtain a list of your authorized URLs, or to authorize additional
>   URLs:
>
> 1. Log in to the Google Enterprise Support Portal.
> 2. From the left side
>      menu, click Maps: Manage Client ID.
>
> You may add up to 100 URLs at a
>   time, to a total of 3000 URLs. If you require higher limits, please
>   contact Google Enterprise Support.
>
> The following considerations apply regarding URLs that are authorized:
>
> **The domain name or IP address does not have to be publicly accessible.**
>   For example, `http://myintranet` and `http://192.168.1.1` are valid
>   entries.
>
> **All subdomains of a specified domain are also authorized** 
>   For example, if http://example.com is authorized, then
>   http://www.example.com is also authorized. The reverse is not true; if
>   http://www.example.com is authorized, http://example.com is not.
>
> **All subpaths of an authorized path are also authorized.** 
>   For example, if http://example.com is authorized, then http://example.com/foo is also
>   authorized. In addition, because subdomains of a specified domain are
>   also authorized, http://sub.example.com/bar is authorized.
>
> **Paths are case-sensitive.** For example, http://www.example.com/ThisPath/ is not
>   the same as http://www.example.com/thispath/.
>
> **You may restrict valid URLs to those using certain ports.** For example, if
>   http://example.com:8080/foo is specified, http://example.com is not.
>
> **HTTP and HTTPS protocols are considered different URLs.** For example,
>   if https://example.com is authorized, http://example.com is not. If
>   you'd like to authorize both at once, you may add a domain without
>   using a protocol: example.com/
>
> All of the rules above are applied to
>   each authorization, so you should take care to plan your
>   authorizations carefully. For example, because all subpaths of a
>   specified path are authorized, and all subdomains, you may end up
>   authorizing pages that you didn't intend to. E.g:
>
> http://example.com/ also authorizes http://sub.example.com/path.